# remove msisdn element based on regex

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to remove `msisdn` field from MO calls on TAP3.11, but it doesn't handle the needed.

I want to set a condition, if the Msisdn doesn't start with 962 then remove the element.

My background is only with python, this's the first time with perl. I use it because after searching I believe that only perl can handle TAP files.

```
# Will scan all the calls for MTC's.
foreach $key ( @{$struct->{'transferBatch'}->{'callEventDetails'} } ) {

    foreach ( keys %{$key} ) {

        if ( $_ eq "mobileOriginatedCall" )
        {
            if ( defined $key->{$_}->{'basicCallInformation'} )
            {
                if ( defined $key->{$_}->{'basicCallInformation'}->{'chargeableSubscriber'} )
                {
                    if ( defined $key->{$_}->{'basicCallInformation'}->{'chargeableSubscriber'}->{'simChargeableSubscriber'})
                    {
                        if ( defined $key->{$_}->{'basicCallInformation'}->{'chargeableSubscriber'}->{'simChargeableSubscriber'}->{'msisdn'})
                        {
                            if ($key->{$_}->{'basicCallInformation'}->{'chargeableSubscriber'}->{'simChargeableSubscriber'}->{'msisdn'} =~ /^[962]/)
                            {
                                $key->{$_}->{'basicCallInformation'}->{'chargeableSubscriber'}->{'simChargeableSubscriber'}->{'msisdn'}=();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
...
if ($key->{$_}->{'basicCallInformation'}->{'chargeableSubscriber'}->{'simChargeableSubscriber'}->{'msisdn'} =~ /^(?!962)/)
{
    delete $key->{$_}->{'basicCallInformation'}->{'chargeableSubscriber'}->{'simChargeableSubscriber'}->{'msisdn'};
}
```

**The changes:**

For deleting a key, use **[delete](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/delete.html)**

For a "not starting with" regex, use: `^(?!WHATEVER)`, for example `^(?!962)`